# Count Upwards for ID jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, count, iteration

I have the following HTML structure

```
<div id="test-1-yay"></div>
... bunch of code ...
<div id="test-2-yay"></div>
... bunch of code ...
<div id="test-3-yay"></div>
```

I was wondering how I can use jQuery to basically identify each of these "id's" and then apply some jQuery to them ? I'm new to this so little unsure ? Something like

```
if $('#test-1-yay' || '#test-2-yay' || '#test-3-yay') {
do stuff to all ID's
}
```

But the prob is I want this to continue as it could go to #test-201-yay, #test-202-yay etc ?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **could** use a [substring selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/PR-css3-selectors-20091215/#attribute-substrings) to get *most* of the way there:

```
var divs = $('div[id^=test-]'); // All divs with IDs starting with "test-"
```

...which would work better if you changed the naming convention a bit so the number was at the end. But I think I'd lean toward using some other aspect of the structure (the parent node), or a class, or a `data-xyz` attribute...

**Edit** A *pair* of substring selectors can do it:

```
var divs = $('div[id^=test-]').filter("div[id$=yay]");
```

That gets all of the ones whose IDs start with "test-" and then filters out the ones that don't end with "yay". *Close*, anyway...

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you add a class to the divs?

Comment: That or get them based on the parent element $('#parentid div')

Comment: ah ok - is it possible to iterate the div id or ?

Comment: This is a valid *alternative* but does not answer the actual question.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like:

```
$("div[id^='test']")
```

or

```
$("div[id$='yay']")
```

or try to combine the two

[Manual](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 0):

you could do it like that:

```
$("div[id^=test-]").each(function(){ //selects all dives having the string 'test-' in it
$that = $(this) 
$that.text($that.attr("id").split("-")[1]) //splits the sting by "-" and gives you out the middle part (in your case the number)
})
```

test it here http://jsfiddle.net/aj5Qk/1/